# PHP MD5 Vs MySQL md5

Tags: php, mysql, md5

This is something I have been wondering about. Is it faster to have MySQL handle my md5 hashing or should I let PHP handle it?

Comment: Does it really matter (i.e. do you need to do this on hundreds of thousands or millions of rows?)

Comment: If the `md5` will be for passwords, do not think faster, think slower (the likes of `bcrypt`)!

Comment: don't forget about parsing the query and network/socket latency.

Comment: @pekka yeah its for millions of rows just wanna do some research on md5 its self and playing arond with some cool things about it.

Comment: @Shef I use sha for my passwords

Comment: @OZ_ so ur pointing out the time it takes for the sql server to "eval" the sql string and connection times and stuff. It is a local server for generating the data

Comment: @WojonsTech if you know answer - don't ask.

Comment: @OZ_ I asked this question almost a week ago I have read peoples reposnces and also have done some testing over the week and asked more people in person and was able to get an answer...... I would like to thank everyone that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just comparing the performance, there won't be any noticeable difference (i think the mysql-implementation will be a very very [...] tiny little bit faster).

try to use the solution that results in more redable (and that way easier maintainable) code. for me, this is doing things like hashing in php, but i don't know what your code looks like, so maybe letting mysql do the job is easier for you.

**PS:** if you're using this for passwords, think about using another [algorithm](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) for [hashing](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) (sha256 for example). for more information, take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities) and read about collisions.

Comment: don't worry my password systems involves 512 hashes and salts.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I think the MySQL MD5 implementation will be faster.

PHP's native `md5()` has a bit of a messy implementation of the algorithm. When hashing MD5 with PHP5 I would recommend to use `hash('md5',$var);` which is proved to be faster.

Make your own benchmarks though.

See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) (Comment at the bottom).

```
0.33311605453491: hash/md5
1.0671429634094: md5
```

Comment: I will work on it next I just wanted to make a basic burte force tool. Just to show why not to use md5 for passwords so at work they can go to an md5 generator online and then copy it into my code and my database will list the matching passwords.

Comment: I guess its always best to always use the hash() and not the md5 one

Answer (score 1):

Do some profiling to find out. But it you are having serious performance issues remember the 80-20 rule. It is then best to first find out where the bottle necks are.

My gut feeling is there is not a lot in it. Personally I would put the MD5 with MySql - keep the business logic together.

Comment: This is for a small personal project It wont take long just a few hours but yeah that 80-20 rule kills some people where I work